# Extracting files from a k8s pod

Tags: kubernetes

I am running a function in a k8s pod and the function creates a log file once it finishes. How can I copy the log file to the local machine?

I have searched similar problems and found [this](https://medium.com/@nnilesh7756/copy-directories-and-files-to-and-from-kubernetes-container-pod-19612fa74660). But the `kubectl cp` functions need to be run from the master node. The problem I have is that, I don't know when the function finishes. And once it has finished the container terminates automatically.

I am looking forward to any idea on how to solve this problem.

Comment: have you tried just send this log to stdout?, you can read the logs of a finished pod with kubectl logs and save it to a file with kubectl logs [my-pod] > logs.txt

Comment: ...or use something like an HTTP POST to send the file contents somewhere else?  There's no particular requirement `kubectl cp` runs on the master, it can run anywhere that has API access, but as you note once the Pod exits its files are gone too.

Answer (score -1):

You can just create a bash script that runs
`scp file_from_container user@master_node_ip:/file`

Comment: But when we do this it asks to confirm the SSH connection and requires password ... I would prefer a more straightforward way

Comment: In cloud-hosted Kubernetes environments (GKE, EKS, AKS, ...) or in a production environment, it's very unlikely that non-administrators will be able to have ssh access to the nodes.